# Find the values of $\alpha$ for which the improper integral $\iint_Df_\alpha(x,y)dxdy$ exists

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Study the function $$f_\alpha(x,y)=\frac{x^\alpha}{x^2+y^2},$$
with $\alpha \geq 0$ and the domain $D\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ that in polar coordinates is given by $0\leq r \leq 1$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4}.$

Determine the values of $\alpha$ for which the improper integral exists.

**Update**
I've expressed the integral into polar coordinates which yields the following
$$\iint_D \frac{(r\cos(\theta))^\alpha}{r^2}r\ drd\theta$$ which can be rewritten into 
$$\iint_D r^{\alpha-1}\cos(\theta)^\alpha\ drd\theta$$
But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Care to tell us what you have tried?

Comment: @Mattos I've edited my question as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT 1** In polar coordinates you have $f_\alpha(r,\theta)=r^{\alpha-2}\cos^{\alpha}\theta$ so you have to discuss the to integrals 
$$
\iint_D f_\alpha(r,\theta)r\mathrm d r\mathrm d\theta=\int_0^1 r^{\alpha-1}\mathrm d r\int_0^{\pi/4} \cos^{\alpha}(\theta)\,\mathrm d \theta
$$

**HINT 2**
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^p}\mathrm d x=\begin{cases} +\infty & \text{for } p\leq 1\\
\frac{1}{1-p} & \text{for } p> 1
\end{cases}
$$

**HINT 3**
For the integral with $\cos\theta$, use the fact that for $\theta\in[0,\pi/4]$ we have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\le\cos\theta\le 1$.

Comment: Yes, that is as far as I came myself. But how can I find arguments whether or not the improper integral exists?

Comment: @Whizkid95 What happens to the integral in $r$ when $\alpha < 0$?

Comment: @Mattos The integral doesn't converge then. Okay and as for the $\cos^\alpha$, there it doesn't matter which values for $\alpha$ I try?